# When rendering the animation, shading rules are not visible

Tags: rendering, animation, shaders

I'm yet a beginner, and faced some issues, when trying to do an animation. I applied shading rules (=nodes?) to the surface (plane), they look just as I wanted. But when I do the animation (I want the camera to move above the surface), in the rendered video, the shading rules are not visible, I only see the plane, with the given modifiers. I checked some posts with similar issues, the results said "uncheck "Only show selected" in the graph editor", etc, it did not work for me. By the screenshot I provide, could someone please give me an advice, what do I do wrong?
[image: camera]

[image: plane]

[image: and this is the rendered result]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Sorry, I don't understand the question. Screenshot 3 shows a render. What's wrong with it? What is missing there? I'm also not sure how the *Graph Editor* is related to the shading issues. The *Graph Editor* shows you the keyframes for the camera and the interpolation between the keyframes. It's used for animation.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the fast reply! I just used the graph editor to smoothen the lines. As for the last screenshot, it reflects to my problem: that, in the rendered view (right), the surface is visible, but without the Shading parameters I set before (that would be the grayscale/hillshade "skin"), visible on the left side. I would like the model, with the shadings on the left, to be animated and rendered in the output video too.

Comment: Ah, I see. The render lacks shadows and looks flat. Does the *Displace* generate all the geometry? Is the plane flat without it? Maybe it's the sun that is in the high noon position and kills all shadows. It's hard to tell only from the screenshots.